# display only hundreds and thousands in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I need to create a dropdown which will give opportunity to choose only hundreds and thousands `(100, 200, 300, 400, ..., 1000, 2000, 3000...10000, etc...)`.

I tried this:

```
for (i=100;i<=10000;i++){
   $selectBox.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
}
```

But with above code `i`variable also counts 101,102,103,... but I need only hundreds and thousands.

Any ideas please?

Comment: did you try any code? If yes, please update your question with that code sample also..

Comment: So loop with a step and append the option elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, The trick is so add 100 to `i` in each iteration.

```js
var $selectBox = $('select');
for (i=100;i<=10000;i+=100){
   $selectBox.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  
</select>
```

Comment: Ohh yes, I was missing i+=100 this part. Thank you @Mosh Feu